# why does this error occur during fetch data from the backend

Tags: reactjs, authentication, fetch, jwt

I have a problem in the signin component when I try to login using the method that have been created below.

Here is the example of the code :

```
export default function Signin(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        error: '',
        redirectToReferrer: false,
    });

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const user = {
            email: values.email || undefined,
            password: values.password || undefined,
        };

        signin(user).then((data) => {
            if (data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
            } else {
                auth.authenticate(data, () => {
                    setValues({ ...values, error: '', redirectToReferrer: true });
                });
            }
        });
    };

    const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
        setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
    };

    const { from } = props.location.state || {
        from: {
            pathname: '/',
        },
    };

    const { redirectToReferrer } = values;
    if (redirectToReferrer) {
        return <Redirect to={from} />;
    }
}
```

If I save this code the error comes up:

> can not read property state of undefined.

The login form appears when I comment out this {from}. But another error comes when I hit submit button:

> cannot read property error of undefined.

Here is my sign in method :

```
const signin = async (user) => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/auth/signin', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify(user),
        });
        return await response.json();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

and the auth method:

```
const auth = {

    authenticate(jwt, cb) {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined')
            sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', JSON.stringify(jwt));
        cb();
    },
};

export default auth;
```

Comment: `can not read property state of undefined`, to resolve this `props.location && props.location.state || ...`

Comment: @Naren solved. thank you so much bro

Comment: Glad, It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, I see these two places you might get error:

`props.location.state and data.error`.

To resolve `can not read property state of undefined`, Add one more safe check:

```
const { from } = props.location && props.location.state || {
    from: {
        pathname: '/',
    },
};
```

And for this one: `cannot read property error of undefined`

```
signin(user).then((data) => {
   if (data && data.error) {
      setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
   } else {
      auth.authenticate(data, () => {
         setValues({ ...values, error: '', redirectToReferrer: true });
      });
  }
});
```